# How to remove data redundancy in a table?

Tags: logic, normalization

```
F1  F2  F3  C1  C2  C3
------------------------------------------------
A   B   C   1       
D   E   F   2       
A   B   C       3   
D   E   F       4   
A   B   C           5
D   E   F           6
```

i have a table like this.
i need my table to be free from Data redundancy
like this

```
F1  F2  F3  C1  C2  C3
-----------------------
A   B   C   1   3   5
D   E   F   2   4   6
```

i am unable to figure out the optimized logic.
can someone help me out.?

Comment: Are you asking how to turn one into another, or how to save as second in the first place? And how much data are we talking about? Are you able to get everything into memory?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 2):

I will assume you are talking about a table in a RDBMS.

That process is called normalization.

The problem is caused because `TABLE1` doesn't have a primary key or at least a unique index to begin with.

If `TABLE1` had a PK (or a unique index), say `F1,F2,F3`, you could not have inserted more than one row with the same values fort those columns. That would have forced you to update the rows instead of inserting a new one.

Your question is not clear, but if what you want is somehow get `TABLE2` from `TABLE1`, this would do it:

```
create table2 as 
select
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    max(c1) c1,
    max(c2) c2,
    max(c3) c3
from
    table1
group by
    f1, f2, f3
```

as long as there is no overlapping values as the sample seems to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what non-optimized logic you've tried, but this works on the dataset example you gave:

```
select 
     f1
    , f2
    , f3
    , max(c1) as c1
    , max(c2) as c2
    , max(c3) as c3
from #RawData
group by f1, f2, f3
```